# How "small" can an ordinal be made by forcing?

Tags: lo.logic, forcing, ordinal-numbers

I know that forcing essentially does not change the ordinals, but by small I mean in comparison with other ordinals whose definition might not be stable under forcing, like the smallest uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ or the Church-Kleene ordinal.

For example, given an ordinal in the ground model one can always make it countable in a forcing model, hence it can become smaller than $\omega_1$ after forcing (the $\omega_1$ of the forcing model of course).

My question is can we do better ? Is there some smaller class (downward closed) of ordinals such that any ordinal can be "put into this class" by forcing ?

Typically: can every ordinal become a recursive ordinal after forcing ? (i.e. smaller than the Church-Kleene ordinal)

Or is there obstructions preventing such a thing for any class of ordinals smaller than the class of all countable ordinals ?

Comment: You definitely cannot make a nonrecursive ordinal recursive by forcing. Being recursive is witnessed by a Turing machine, i.e. a natural number, and these aren't affected by forcing.

Comment: You can change the set of ordinals which are countable in HOD by forcing, and this set can be smaller than $\omega_1^V$.